Usage of linearity of power of a point to prove equality of powers
I was reading a solution to problem 15 of 2016 AIME I. Here is the problem statement and a diagram:

Circles $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ intersect at points $X$ and $Y$. Line $\ell$ is tangent to $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ at $A$ and $B$, respectively, with line $AB$ closer to point $X$ than to $Y$. Circle $\omega$ passes through $A$ and $B$ intersecting $\omega_1$ again at $D \neq A$ and intersecting $\omega_2$ again at $C \neq B$. The three points $C$, $Y$, $D$ are collinear, $XC = 67$, $XY = 47$, and $XD = 37$. Find $AB^2$.

(It has a whole bunch of other points and lines, just ignore them)

Solution 7 used linearity of power of a point in order to find that two powers were equal. After doing some research, I found that the statement of linearity of power of a point is as follows:

And here is the usage:

Claim: $AB^2 = DY \cdot YC$.


Proof. Define the linear function $F(\bullet) := \text{Pow}(\bullet, (ADY)) - \text{Pow}(\bullet, (ABCD))$. Since $\overline{BY}$ is parallel to the radical axis $\overline{AD}$ of $(ADY)$ and $(ABCD)$ by our previous parallelism, $F(B)=F(Y)$. Note that $F(B)=AB^2$ while $F(Y)=DY \cdot YC$, so we conclude. $\square$

(No need to check that $\overline{BY}$ is parallel to the radical axis $\overline{AD}$, this is true.)
What exactly is meant by $F$ is linear? When we look the proof of the theorem,


it appears that this is the definition of the linearity of $F$. But, where in the solution does it use the fact that $F$ satisfies this property? It seems to me that they only used the fact that $\overline{BY}$ was parallel to the radical axis. This solution would make sense if we had that $F(P) = k$ is a line parallel to the radical axis for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$. This would imply that $F(B) = F(Y) = k$ for some $k$. This fact is not too difficult to prove (Pythagorean theorem). However, I'm struggling to understand how this ties into the statement given by the "Linearity of Power of a Point" theorem. Does the theorem imply this fact? Or am I misunderstanding linearity? Or is the solution writer referring to something else?
Any help will be appreciated!

Looks like linearity of $F$ has been proved only when the sum of the coefficients is one. This is not the usual definition of linearity, but for our purpose it's enough.
We have, for some number $\lambda\ne1$
(if $\lambda=1$ other decompositions are possible):
$$
B=Y+\lambda(A-D)=\lambda A+(1-\lambda)C,
$$
where:
$$
C={1\over1-\lambda}Y+{-\lambda\over1-\lambda}D.
$$
Hence, by the linearity of $F$ and taking into account that $F(A)=F(D)=0$, we have:
$$
F(B)=\lambda F(A)+(1-\lambda) F(C)=
(1-\lambda)\left({1\over1-\lambda}F(Y)
+{-\lambda\over1-\lambda}F(D) \right)
=F(Y).
$$

Wouldn't the same proof imply that $F(A - D) = F(A) - F(D) = 0$, therefore $A-D$ must lie on the radical axis when it clearly isn't?

@crxyz I don't understand your remark: $A-D$ is a vector, it doesn't "lie" anywhere. And line $AD$ is the radical axis of the circles defining $F$.

As in the endpoint of the vector. Am I misunderstanding this "addition" or "subtraction" of points?

I think I understand your concern: I updated my answer.
